# Unable to send or receive data via a FIFO in C

Tags: c, process, signals, mkfifo

I'm workng on a C program with which I'd like to implement a scenario
when a parent and two children processes are communicating with each other.
A child should send a real-time signal to the parent.
That's not a problem. However, in case the parent would like to write the FIFO in order for the child to access its message, then I'm unable to achieve the deisred goal.

As you can see so far I'm only experimenting with a single child. If this setup will work then I'd like to expand the problem to children.

I attempted to accomplish the desired outcome with the help of the `SIGRTMIN+1` constant.
With it I ensure the presence of a real-time signal. In the parent following the `sigsuspend` call I attempt to open the FIFO for writing only. In the child following the `sigqueue` call I attempt to open the FIFO for reading only.

EDIT:
I know that printf() inside a handler function body is not desired, but I'm only including that for experimenting purposes.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define SIG_CHLD_1_READY SIGRTMIN+1

int main()
{
pid_t parent = getpid();
sigset_t newmask, oldmask;
char* fifo = "/tmp/nohope";
mkfifo( fifo, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR );

    if ( fork() == 0) {    /*Child*/
        union sigval sval; 
        sval.sival_int = 1;
    
        sigqueue( parent, SIG_CHLD_1_READY, sval); 

        int fd = open( fifo, S_IRUSR);
        int a;
        while( read(fd, &a, sizeof( int ) ) == sizeof( int ) );

        printf("%d\n", a );
        
        _exit(0);
        
    }
    else {                             /* Parent */
        struct sigaction action;
        void catchit();

        sigemptyset(&newmask);
        sigaddset(&newmask, SIG_CHLD_1_READY);
        sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newmask, &oldmask);

        action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO; 
        action.sa_sigaction = catchit;

        if (sigaction(SIG_CHLD_1_READY, &action, NULL) == -1) { 
            perror("sigusr: sigaction");
            _exit(1);
        }
        sleep(1); 

        sigsuspend(&oldmask);

        int fd = open( fifo, S_IWUSR);
        int a = 69;
        write(fd, &a, sizeof( int ));

        
        wait( NULL );
    }
}
void catchit(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *extra) 
{
       void *ptr_val = info->si_value.sival_ptr;
       int int_val = info->si_value.sival_int;
       printf("Signal %d, value %d  received from parent\n", signo, int_val);
       _exit(0);
}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

EDIT:
Solution was to remove _exit(0);

Comment: Is the child sending the signal to the parent before the parent does anything to block or handle the signal?

Comment: The signal handling part is alright. The problem is the lack of pipefunctioning.

Comment: You pass _mode_ flags to the _oflag_ argument of `open`. What happens if you fix that?

Comment: @pilcrow If only there were some error checking...

Comment: You could send the signal from the child before the parent has its signal handling set up.  Fix: set up the parental signal handling before forking the child.  The child might, or might not, need to reset the signal handling. Style hint: Don't declare functions inside another one — declare them outside.  (Yes, it's syntactically legal, but it is bad style.). Fix: either define `catchit()` — as a `static` function since it won't be used outside this source file — before `main`, or declare it `static void catchit(…);` before `main()` and implement it afterwards.

Comment: @pilcrow — the mode is only needed if the flags include `O_CREAT`.  The signature for POSIX [`open()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) is `int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...);` and the third (`mode`) argument is optional and only relevant when `O_CREAT` is specified.

Comment: It still does not work, even if I run the modified version suggested by Leffler.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yes. The OP is calling `open` incorrectly, putting the value of the optional third argument in the second argument position.

Comment: @pilcrow — Oh, my bad.  O_RDONLY and O_WRONLY.  Yes!  Sorry.

Comment: solution was to remove _exit(0)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the nature of the problem was never clearly articulated, and the OP commented that the matter was solved with a one line change.  There's no future educational value in this question.